# Formulating an Anomaly Detection method for a dataset based on time

Tags: time-series, clustering, data-mining, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have the following data (temporal feature) for **n** videos of given length:

1. start times of all the users who watched the video
2. duration of the video viewed

Now, given a video (given the start times and durations of all users who watched this video) of the same length as the earlier n videos, I would like to detect whether this video was watched by bots (by comparing it with the data I have for n videos which I'm assuming to be pure) I'm assuming that there will be a statistically significant difference between the given two features for a botted video and a genuine video.

How can I detect such an anomaly? What models can I use?
One thing that comes to mind is to model the n videos as a distribution over two variables and compare the distance in distributions between this and the video which is to be tested.

How else can I model the problem?
Note: This is not a time-series anomaly detection problem as such.

Comment: Well, how do the bots in your data set behave? What makes a bot different from a "real" user? Aren't smartphone zombies kind of bots, too?

Comment: Hmm.. At the moment they come online in lockstep (almost all of them simultaneously together) and stay for almost all of the duration of the video. But if an approach is designed against this, isn't it easily circumvented? Like for example by drawing start times and view times stochastically. Am I looking at tackling a problem with very little at hand? Regarding smartphone zombies, we aren't really worried as long as there's a human watching, however disinterested he is. Views should reflect true popularity of the content - that's the objective.

Comment: Well, it all depends on the data you have. If you only have time and duration, you need to find something that makes these unusual compared to real users.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. But what kind of models can I build/use for this given that I have these two features as datapoints..? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing that will be bullet-proof. But try various classifiers and measure their performance.